# how to reveal/unrveal password inside input in Data Driven Forms (it npm react package)?

Tags: reactjs, forms, package

I have a custom form imported from node_module as `import FormRenderer from "@data-driven-forms/react-form-renderer/form-renderer";`

this form requires schema in json object to then convert them to html element, I want to add icon and onClick functionality to show the password using this form?

```
 schema = {
      name: "password",
      label: "Password",
      type: "password",
      component: componentTypes.TEXT_FIELD,
      placeholder: "Password",
      placeholdericon: "/images/lock.svg",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a component that supports this functionality. In this case we need a custom component.

Have a look at [this codepen](https://codesandbox.io/embed/data-driven-forms-example-forked-mnufzp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for an example.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormRenderer from "@data-driven-forms/react-form-renderer/form-renderer";
import useFieldApi from "@data-driven-forms/react-form-renderer/use-field-api";
import useFormApi from "@data-driven-forms/react-form-renderer/use-form-api";

const Button = ({ children, label, ...props }) => (
  <button {...props}>{label}</button>
);

const FormTemplate = ({ formFields }) => {
  const { handleSubmit, onCancel } = useFormApi();
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleSubmit();
      }}
    >
      {formFields}
      <Button type="submit" label="Submit" />
      <Button type="button" label="cancel" onClick={onCancel} />
    </form>
  );
};

const Password = (props) => {
  const {
    customProp,
    label,
    input,
    isRequired,
    meta: { error, touched },
    icon,
    ...rest
  } = useFieldApi(props);

  const [hidden, hide] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={input.name}>
        {isRequired && <span>*&nbsp;</span>}
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        type={hidden ? "password" : "text"}
        id={input.name}
        {...input}
        {...rest}
      />
      <button onClick={() => hide(!hidden)} type="button">
        {icon} {hidden ? "Show" : "Hide"}
      </button>
      {touched && error && <p>{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

const componentMapper = {
  password: Password,
};

const schema = {
  fields: [
    {
      component: "password",
      name: "password",
      label: "Your password",
      icon: "",
    },
  ],
};

const ComponentMapper = () => {
  return (
    <FormRenderer
      componentMapper={componentMapper}
      FormTemplate={FormTemplate}
      schema={schema}
      onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
      onCancel={() => console.log("cancel action")}
    />
  );
};

export default ComponentMapper;
```